# iOS app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Exception breakpoint not pointing to code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, backtrace

I'm working on upgrading an old project to work on newer versions of iOS, but I keep getting a crash on the launch screen with this error:

> error: memory read failed for 0x7c37d3000

**And**

> Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x1c7c37d309d)

To find out where in the code this was, I enabled zombie objects, and set a breakpoint for all exceptions. When the app crashes, the breakpoint does not highlight a section of code, but instead does this:

**Image of breakpoint navigator**

[image: Screen Shot]

It says something about `libobjc.A.dylib`, and `libc++abi.dylib`, so I am assuming this is not part of my code? Also, clicking on the breakpoint does not lead me to a place in code like people say it usually does.

Here's the result of bt in the lldb console (backtrace):

```
* thread #4, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x1c7c37d309d)
  * frame #0: 0x00000007c37d309d
```

I read that from this back trace you can determine a method or file etc but this output does not seem to have that.

How can I determine where exactly in the code this error is coming from?   Let me know if I should provide anything else, as I am new to this site. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I should probably mention that the app crashes with this on simulator: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mV9.png)
Here's the backtrace for that error:

```
> * thread #3, stop reason = signal SIGABRT   * frame #0: 0x0000000107d5cb66 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
>     frame #1: 0x0000000107d96080 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
>     frame #2: 0x00000001012b7405 libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_pthread_kill + 325
>     frame #3: 0x0000000107b09c45 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
>     frame #4: 0x00000001012b669c libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_abort + 108
>     frame #5: 0x00000001008d5c0f GiFmojo`inittls + 431
>     frame #6: 0x00000001008d5a32 GiFmojo`runtime.etext + 98
>     frame #7: 0x00000001006fe19c GiFmojo`runtime.rt0_go + 140
>     frame #8: 0x0000000107d93661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
>     frame #9: 0x0000000107d9350d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
>     frame #10: 0x0000000107d92bf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
```

The difference in crash reasons is very confusing.

**EDIT:** Here's the screenshot of the debug navigator:

[image: screen shot]

**EDIT:** I disabled zombie objects and it now alternates between Thread 4 and Thread 5, with error:

> error: memory read failed for 0xaeb3f7600
>
> Thread 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x20aeb3f7693)

For Thread 5. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Did you got this working ?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Not yet.

Comment: Did you add `libz.tbl` library in your project ?

Comment: No, I don't think so... what is that?

Comment: Since this crash occurs on simulator only, and the project is about photo/image, it might due to the setup process of your camera. On simulator, some AVFoundation object cannot be initialized, and if the setup failed, it returns error code or nil object rather than throw catch-able exception. If you forget check the return value, it might cause unexpected crash later, when you use those invalid return value

Answer (score 0):

Hey possible problem is debug-disassembly option could you

go to debug tab -> Debug Workflow -> Always show debug disassembly

and uncheck that ?

Comment: Hi, looks like the Always show disassembly under Debug workflow under debut tab does not have a check. Is this what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: yes so for me when I disabled that it worked and it started pointing out to the code .

Comment: Can you try enabling other breakpoint options also like Swift error, exception, symbolic, constraint error or you can give us some steps reproduce this since it might be totally related your project setup but not sure

Comment: Hi, I tried all of the breakpoints but none of them seemed to make a difference. I am sorry, but the project is very large and I was just given this to update, so I don't really know how you could reproduce. Thanks!

Comment: I also have this warning: 
Not running swift-stdlib-tool: ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES is enabled, but the product type 'com.apple.product-type.library.static' is not a wrapper type. (in target 'Pods-GiFmojo').   Is this related?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but take project backup and do a pod install --verbose once, clean build and see if its happening due to some setup issue or remove this Pods-GIFmojo and then see if the app runs. if we can narrow down to a library that is causing exception then we can fix that

Comment: Hi, I tried to delete the pods project and reinstall, but nothing seemed to change. The app crashes the the error I added to the post, but crashes on device with a different error. Does this reveal anything? Also, is there any other way to determine what library is causing the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have memory access errors, such as reading unreadable location, writing to unallocated (or already freed) location, and so on.

There are debugging technique for this kind of problems, but it's very difficult.

Take a look at this document: [Enabling the Malloc Debugging Features](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001884-CJBJFIDD)

Start with malloc guard if possible(locating bad write), last resort is the searching the offending memory address from the malloc logging output.

Answer (score 0):

> Clearing DerivedData solved my issue.

My app was working fine in real device, it was crashing only in simulator.

Steps i tried:

- I have **uninstall and re install** app in simulator, but still didn't
  work.
- In simulator selected **Erase All content and Settings** in simulator, but still didn't work.

Please try to clear **DerivedData** hopefully it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Try using "Symbolic Breackpoint" in the "Breackpoints" tab. Very often it helps to find the place of the crash of the application. Hope to help[image]

Comment: Hi, what should I put for the symbol and condition in this case? Thanks!

Comment: yes since we are not sure what is causing the exception so better to put this check I guess so

Comment: @user10747039 Add some name to at, and the application should stop at the site of the crash

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Should I add any name to the symbol?

Comment: Press Add action